# How can I force linking with a static library when a shared library of same name is present

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, ld

Suppose I have a file `main.cpp` which uses `sin()` function which is defined in `libmath`. Also suppose that we have both libmath.a and libmath.so available in the same directory. Now if I issue the command `g++ -o main main.cpp -lmath` the default behaviour of Linux is to link to the shared library `libmath.so`. I want to know is there a way to force the program to link with the static library `libmath.a` without deleting or moving the shared library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [g++ linker: force static linking if static library exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698321/g-linker-force-static-linking-if-static-library-exists)

Answer (score 32):

You'll need to pass the -static to the linker, but only for particular libraries you want. e.g.:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -Wl,-Bstatic -lmath -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Comment: Surely it shouldn't matter for gcc/binutils, -static and -Bstatic are synonyms in the GNU linker.

Answer (score 15):

If your linker supports `-l:<filename>` you may use:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -l:libmath.a
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this function:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp /path_to/libmath.a
```