# Static compiling using CMake- cannot find -lgtk-3

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I'm trying to do a static compile of a C++ project using CMake, but it seems to still be linking dynamically. I'm new to CMake so I'm not entirely sure of how everything works.

This is my project root directory's CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
SET(CMAKE_LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -g -Werror")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

#project(wwest-outreach-app.out)
project(WWEST LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
include_directories(include)

file(COPY data DESTINATION bin/)
```

/src/'s CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -g -Werror -lpthread -std=c++0x -lglut")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES OFF)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE
                               main.cc
                               audiofile.cc
                               button.cc
                               entity.cc
                               entity_group.cc
                               splash_screen_state.cc
                               sprite.cc
                               signal.cc
                               signal_chunk.cc
                               sound_edit_state.cc
                               splash_screen_state.cc
                               sprite.cc
                               state.cc
                               state_stack.cc
                               waveform_chunk_display.cc
                               waveform_chunk_select_button.cc
                               waveform_chunk_select_display.cc
                               waveform_component_display.cc
                               waveform_display.cc
                               wwest_app.cc
                               play_original_button.cc
                               low_pass_button.cc
                               high_pass_button.cc
                               mid_pass_button.cc
                               reset_button.cc
                               play_modified_button.cc
                               speed_up_button.cc
                               slow_down_button.cc
                               pause_original_button.cc
                               pause_modified_button.cc
                               message_display.cc
                               play_original_chunk_button.cc
                               play_modified_chunk_button.cc
                               stop_original_button.cc
                               play_button_base.cc
                               pause_button_base.cc
                               scroll_right_button.cc
                               scroll_left_button.cc
                               goto_start_end_button.cc
                               file_load_button.cc)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
pkg_search_module(SDL2_IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image>=2.0.0)
pkg_search_module(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf)
pkg_search_module(NFD REQUIRED sdl2)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_library(OpenGL REQUIRED)
#add_library(libGLU /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${NFD_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})

pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})
# Add other flags to the compiler
add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
                                      ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
                                      ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES}
                                      ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
                                      ${NFD_LIBRARIES}
                                      ${GTK3_LIBRARIES}
                                      nfd
                                      pthread
                                      )
```

I added the -static flags as per answers in similar questions like [CMake and Static Linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991225/cmake-and-static-linking?rq=1)
and
[Compiling a static executable with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648357/compiling-a-static-executable-with-cmake)
, but now I'm getting errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so'
```

if I try adding

```
add_library(libGLU /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a)
```

then I get

```
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "libGLU".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: libGLU
```

Then, I put `set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)` after `add_executable` only to get the above link language error for `cmake ./` and and `make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'src/CMakeFiles/libGLU.dir/build'.` for `make`.

Super lost and confused. Help please?

EDIT: I updated my question and my Cmake code to reflect my efforts to fix this and to be more specific with the error I'm getting.

EDIT 2: After trying some suggestions I was given I'm now getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o): In function `g_get_user_database_entry':
(.text+0x249): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o): In function `g_get_user_database_entry':
(.text+0xcf): warning: Using 'getpwnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o): In function `g_get_user_database_entry':
(.text+0x106): warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/WWEST.dir/build.make:1060: recipe for target 'bin/WWEST' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/WWEST] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/WWEST.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/WWEST.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Add C or CXX to your `project` call or add an according `enable_language`. BTW, your project name is weird, why calling it something ending with .out?

Comment: You can't give a library in `add_library()`. You have to for the correct static linking solutions for all external libraries you include. Generally speaking you could try setting [`CMAKE_LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC.html) to `TRUE`.

Comment: I changed `project` to `project(WWEST LANGUAGES CXX)` and added `SET(CMAKE_LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC TRUE)`. Now I'm getting an error that I pasted at the bottom of my question. `libgtk-3-dev` is already installed.

Comment: Got the same problem with linking. Answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40554704/6726791