# Link libc statically

Tags: cmake, libc

I am trying to make a static executable with CMake 3.15. I am building on Alpine Linux (hence with musl), and currently, my executable's ldd output is:

```
# ldd my_executable
    /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7fc6f7977000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7fc6f65b3000)
    libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7fc6f7977000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7fc6f659f000)
```

I can set `target_link_options(my_executable PRIVATE -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)`, and they got linked statically:

```
# ldd my_executable
    /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7fc6f7977000)
    libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7fc6f7977000)
```

But I can't manage to get musl to link statically. I tried (with clean builds, to make sure that the configure step starts from zero):

1. Adding `-static` to `target_link_options` above.
2. `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")` before the call to `add_executable(my_executable ...)`
3. Adding `-static` to `target_link_libraries(my_executable lib1 lib2 -static)`

When I run CMake in `VERBOSE=1` mode, it always ends the linking command with:

```
... -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl -lrt -lm -lpthread
```

I believe that this is my issue: I want to get rid of that `-Bdynamic`. What am I missing? Is this `-Bdynamic` coming from one of my dependencies? I build them all from sources as static (`.a`) libraries, so how could they be linking libc dynamically? Or would I need to patch them all to add `-static` when I build them?

Comment: For option 2, the variable should be `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`. Also, to be clear about option 3, this means you tried `target_link_libraries(my_executable -static)`? It may help to remove your CMake cache between each build attempt.

Comment: Sorry, typo. And yes, I tried what you said, let me edit. I also made clean builds, but I can try again.

Comment: Edited, @squareskittles! Note: I added `-static` at the end (after the libraries). Does it matter?

Comment: While you can do `set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_DYNAMIC_C_FLAGS "")`  It's better to do it [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991225/cmake-and-static-linking).

Comment: nice! `LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC` and `LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC` allowed me to have now all but ld-musl linked statically. I don't know why, but this one is still dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hinted by KamilCuk's comment, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991225/cmake-and-static-linking) seems to have the solution. Still, I'm not doing exactly the same, therefore I'll keep this answer, too.

For the target executable that I want statically linked:

```
add_executable(my_executable main.cpp)
```

I had to set the following properties/options:

```
set_target_properties(my_executable PROPERTIES LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC ON)
set_target_properties(my_executable PROPERTIES LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC ON)

target_link_options(my_executable PRIVATE -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static)
```

Some notes:

- `LINK_SEARCH_*_STATIC` were useful to remove `-Bdynamic` from the linking command.
- I never managed to remove `-ldl` from the linking command, but it seems like `dl` did not get link eventually (presumably because it is not used).
- `ldd` was not enough to verify that `my_executable` is statically linked. `readelf -l my_executable` showed that it does not have an `INTERP` header, and there is currently no such thing as a dynamic binary without it (using musl).
- It turns out that checking whether a binary is statically linked or not is not so straightforward :-).