# Generate Static Executable with CMake

Tags: c, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

Please bear with this question, it is rather long.

**TLDR: A CMake project with a subdirectory library links successfully, but creates a dynamic executable.**

Code Available at: https://github.com/georcon/cmake-issue

Also **Note:** I have read all related questions/answers, and none answer this question.

I have created the following minimal example:

### Create a statically-linked executable (Works correctly)

(Git Tag: SimpleExecutable)

**main.c**

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
        uuid_t some_uuid;
        char uuid_str[40];

        uuid_generate(some_uuid);
        uuid_unparse(some_uuid, uuid_str);

        printf("UUID: %s\n", uuid_str);
        return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(cmake-issue VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "Static target issue" LANGUAGES C)

add_executable(main-dynamic main.c)
target_link_libraries(main-dynamic uuid)

add_executable(main-static main.c)
target_link_libraries(main-static uuid -static)
```

**Result**

```
ldd main-dynamic
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc406bb000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f76781cd000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7677fdb000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f76781eb000)

ldd main-static
not a dynamic executable
```

### Create a static executable with library

(Git Tag: ExecutableWithLibrary)

**lib/lib.h**

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

void PrintUUID();

#endif //LIB_H
```

**lib/lib.c**

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintUUID(){

        uuid_t some_uuid;
        char uuid_str[40];

        uuid_generate(some_uuid);
        uuid_unparse(some_uuid, uuid_str);

        printf("UUID: %s\n", uuid_str);
}
```

**lib/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(testlibrary VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "Static target issue - Library" LANGUAGES C)

add_library(testlib lib.c)
target_link_libraries(testlib uuid)
```

**main.c**

```
#include "lib/lib.h"

int main(){
        PrintUUID();
        return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(cmake-issue VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "Static target issue" LANGUAGES C)

add_subdirectory(lib ./bin)
link_directories(./lib/ ./bin)

add_executable(main-dynamic main.c)
add_dependencies(main-dynamic testlib)
target_link_libraries(main-dynamic libtestlib.a uuid -static)

link_libraries("-static")

add_executable(main-static main.c)
target_link_libraries(main-static PUBLIC "-static" libtestlib.a uuid)
add_dependencies(main-static testlib)
#target_link_libraries(main-static libtestlib.a uuid -static)
```

**Result**

```
ldd main-static
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe6b485000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fc67edd3000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc67ebe1000)
        /lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc67edec000)
```

Looking at the linker command:

> ~/cmake_issue$ cat CMakeFiles/main-static.dir/link.txt /usr/bin/cc
> CMakeFiles/main-static.dir/main.c.o  -o main-static
> -L/home/georcon/cmake_issue/./lib  -L/home/georcon/cmake_issue/./bin  -Wl,-rpath,/home/georcon/cmake_issue/./lib:/home/georcon/cmake_issue/./bin -static -static
> -Wl,-Bstatic -ltestlib -Wl,**-Bdynamic** -luuid

**Why does CMake not generate a statically-linked executable in this case?**

Comment: The library that is being built is a shared library by default, unless you specify otherwise. Try adding STATIC like this: `add_library(testlib STATIC lib.c)`, and have a look at the CMake documentation of add_library(): https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/command/add_library.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: You need to tell CMake that you **prefer static linking** with the libraries.
This is done by setting property `LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC`. Also you need to tell CMake to not reset static linkage at the end of the libraries list.
This is done by setting property `LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC`:

```
set_target_properties(main-static PROPERTIES
  LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC ON
  LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC ON
)
```

See also that question: [CMake and Static Linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991225/cmake-and-static-linking).

### What is going on

Actually, the linker option `-static` not only disables PIE, but also affects on further libraries listed in the command... unless `-dynamic` is specified.

CMake has a notion about "**default linking type**", which is applied for every library (`uuid` in your case) for which CMake cannot deduce its type. Moreover, CMake **maintains** that default linking type after each library it adds into the linker's command line. And CMake expects the same behavior from the user, who manually adds linker flags.

Your first example is **wrong**, but suddenly **works**:

You add `-static` which turns current linkage type to **static**. And thus you break CMake expectations about current linkage type.

When produce the linker option for link with uuid, CMake expects that current linkage is **dynamic**. So, CMake doesn't add `-dynamic` linker switch.

That time CMake expectations doesn't correspond to the reality, which in turn corresponds to your expectations: `uuid` is linked statically.

But the second example reveals the problem:

When linking with `libtestlib.a` library, CMake is perfectly aware that this is a static library, and thus adds `Wl,-Bstatic` option before that library. But CMake need to maintain default linkage after every option, so it adds `-Wl,-Bdynamic` after the library:

```
-Wl,-Bstatic -ltestlib -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

With such options CMake **expectations** about default dynamic linking corresponds to the reality: `uuid` is linked dynamically. But now that reality doesn't correspond to yours expectations.

Comment: Looks like this was the solution - I still needed to keep ```-static``` at the start of the ```target_link_libraries```. Is this best practice?

Comment: Additionally, the question quoted in this answer directly sets the ```CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS``` - which from reading concluded this is discouraged. Is this correct?