# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Mac OS 10.8

Tags: macos, gcc, ant, ld, llvm-gcc

So generally, I know what this error means.  But here's what's unique to my issue -

1. I do have the (static) library with the symbols the linker is unable to find.  I ran the 'nm' to verify this, explicitly looking for the x86_64 symbols.  They're there.
2. But - I also have a dynamic library in the same location with the same name.  My guess is that the linker is grabbing the .dylib, instead of the .a, and as a result its unable to find the symbols it needs.

I did find this post about forcing static linking when you have static & dynamic libs with the same name - [How can I force linking with a static library when a shared library of same name is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500158/how-can-i-force-linking-with-a-static-library-when-a-shared-library-of-same-name).

The thing is I'm using Ant build scripts and tried a few different things to incorporate the solution in the post above, without much success.

So my questions are -

1. Is my hunch right in #2 above with the "miss" resulting from the library name?
2. Does anyone know of an Ant script solution to this?  Some of the things I've tried in Ant are -
   a. "linkerarg value="static"" <- problem with this is it tries to find a static lib for crt0.o
   b. "linkerarg value="static"" followed by
   "linkerarg value="llibname""

**UPDATE** - I was right about the linker picking up the .dylib instead of the .a - I renamed the static library (.a) to something else and its able to find all the symbols it needs.  Now the question is - how do we explicitly instruct the Ant script to pick up the .a and not the .dylib?

**ANSWER** - its a linker flag called *force_load*.  So -force_load filename.a would do it.

Comment: Any chance you could post a snippet of your buildfile to give context to your use of `linkerarg`s?

Comment: This is what I have Martin - <linkerarg value="-static" />
         <linkerarg value="-lmyLibFile" />
         <linkerarg value="-Wl" />
         <linkerarg value="-dynamic" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a linker flag called *force_load*. So -force_load filename.a would do it.