# Why can't gcc find my static library?

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to link the cspec library into my C project. This is my Makefile located in the tests folder:

```
all: test

test: sample.o
    gcc -Wall -o test sample.o -L ../lib/cspec -llibcspec.a

sample.o: sample.c
    gcc -Wall -c sample.c -I../lib/cspec

clean:
    rm -rf *o test
```

My directory is:

```
/
/src
/lib
/lib/cspec
/tests
```

When I run make I receive the following error:

```
gcc -Wall -o test sample.o -L ../lib/cspec -llibcspec.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcspec.a
```

I have made sure that the the libcspec.a file is located in the lib/cspec folder but to be sure I have also tried placing it within the tests folder and removing the -L command, to no avail.

Comment: Try removing the space after `-L`.

Comment: @Joshua K: no - white space after `-L` is optional and makes no difference. Ditto for `-I`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Change:

```
gcc -Wall -o test sample.o -L ../lib/cspec -llibcspec.a
```

to:

```
gcc -Wall -o test sample.o -L ../lib/cspec -lcspec
```

(By convention, gcc and other *nix compilers automatically add the `lib` prefix and the appropriate suffix.)

Comment: Note that if you happen to have a `libcspec.so` in the same directory as `libcspec.a`, your command will result in linking with the `.so` library. If you'd really like to use the `.a` library, use `-l:cspec.a`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically.)