# Making c++ executable

Tags: c++, g++

I want to build a c++ executable such that all the libraries also get attached to the executable. What is the method of building such an executable? So, that whenever I compile my code using g++ on some other PC (running Ubuntu), it does not need the libraries needed for the running of that executable.

Comment: sounds like you would need to use static linking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically

Comment: Under which environnment ? Windows, Linux, Mac, ... ?

Comment: You still have to make sure that the target OS ABI is compatible.

Comment: You do not "run [your] executable using g++". You *compile* and *link* using `g++` to *get* an executable that you run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you mean is called static linking. Please have a look at this tutorial:

https://sites.google.com/site/malvanos/tutorials/static-linking-with-gcc