# gcc -static: link statically only one specified library

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have compiled my program linked dynamically:

```
gcc -s -o foo foo.c -lcrypto
```

It is linked with following libraries:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff0bff5000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fd68431c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd683f91000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd683d8c000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd683b75000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd68471c000)
```

Now I need to run it on a system, which is missing only one of the linked libraries (`libcrypto.so.1.0.0`).

I can compile my code as statically linked:

```
gcc -static -s -o foo foo.c -lcrypto
```

But the resulting binary is too large, apparently because it links all libraries statically.

**Can I link statically only one library (`libcrypto.so.1.0.0`), and leave the others linked dynamically ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telling gcc directly to link a library statically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically)