# With bazel how do I be/make sure objects taken from cache have been build for the right system/libraries?

Tags: bazel, distributed-computing, distributed-caching, build-cache

I got some strange glibc-related linker errors for builds with distributed build cache configured on build nodes running different Linux distributions.

Now I somehow suspect build artifacts from those machines with different glibc versions getting mixed up, but I don't know how to investigate this.

How do I find out what Bazel takes into account when building the hash for a certain build artifact?

I know I can explicitly set environment variables which then will affect the hash. But how can I be sure a given compiler, a certain version of glibc, etc. will lead to different hashes for built artifacts?

And how do I check/compare what's been taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex topic and a multi-facet question. I am going to answer in the following order:

1. How do I check/compare what's been taken into account?
2. How to investigate against which glibc a build linked?
3. How can I be sure a given compiler, a certain version of glibc, etc. will lead to different hashes for built artifacts?

### How do I check/compare what's been taken into account?

To answer this, you should look into the the execution look, specifically you can read up on https://bazel.build/remote/cache-remote#compare-logs. The [`*.json` execution log](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--execution_log_json_file) should contain everything you need to know (granted, it might be a bit verbose) and is a little easier to process with shell-magic/your editor.

### How to investigate against which glibc a build linked?

From the execution log, you can get all the required hashes to retrieve cached artifacts/binaries from your remote cache. Given these files, you should be able to use standard tools to get to the glibc version (`ldd -r -v binary | grep GLIBC`).

### How can I be sure a given compiler, a certain version of glibc, etc. will lead to different hashes for built artifacts?

This depends on the way you have setup for compilation toolchain. The best case would be a fully hermetic compilation toolchain, where all necessary files are declared using attributes like https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_toolchain.compiler_files.

But this would also mean to lock-down the [compiler sysroot](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/sysroot). This should include all libraries you are linking against if you want full hermeticity. If you want to use some system libraries, you need to tell `bazel` where to find them and to factor in their hash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43419786/20546409 or https://www.stevenengelhardt.com/2021/09/22/practical-bazel-depending-on-a-system-provided-c-cpp-library/

If you use the auto-detected compiler toolchain, some tricks are used to lock-down the sysroot paths, but expect some non-hermiticity. https://github.com/limdor/bazel-examples/tree/master/linux_toolchain is a nice write-up how to move from the auto-detected toolchain to something more hermetic.

#### The hack

Of course, you can hack around this. Note, this is inherently a bad idea:

- create a script that inspects the system, determines everything important like the `glibc` version, maybe the linux distribution (flavor)
- creates a string describing this variation and hash-summing it
- use that as the instance key/name for your remote cache

Comment: Can you elaborate on why "the hack" is a bad idea? Currently to me it looks like while Bazel _could_ find those differences automatically and take them into account, it doesn't. So you could either copy everything that _might_ effect your build and make it part of your toolchain or you create a hash of it and make sure you don't have false cache hits. What might happen to me if I did the latter?

Comment: Yes, it is a bad idea because you introduce a source for cache misses that might be difficult to communicate to your team members. Also it is unclear when you have to inspect your system. Preferably on every build, because a system upgrade could have upgraded the `glibc`. But then you need a wrapper around `bazel` which might confuse some IDE integration or command line completion.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood your answer correcty: you're suggesting to create a fully hermetic build environment which guarantees cache misses if anything changes. And a sub-optimal way to also cause those cache misses would be to manually create a textual list of properties and using those via `--set_action_env` to bind them to the target hash. Right?

Comment: I was thinking about the "instance name" as described in https://github.com/buchgr/bazel-remote. And a scripts that generates a `--remote_cache` flag that contains a hashed instance name. But yes, action envs should work aswell.