# g++ -static flag replaces the dynamic library loader

Tags: linux, makefile, linker, g++, ld

First of all I would like to give some background information to avoid the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

I am trying to compile a c++ program using makefiles and g++. I also have to build any dependencies statically into the program, but not the 'system libraries' (`libz.so`, `libdl.so`, `libstdc++.so`, `libm.so`, `libpthread.so`, `libc.so` and `libgcc.so`).

To achieve this I specify `-static` as linker flag, then all dependencies that have to be statically linked and then I use the `-Wl, -Bdynamic` option, that should tell the linker to link every library, after this option, to be linked in dynamically including the 'system libraries' because they get linked last.(please correct me if I am wrong.)

```
LDFLAGS += -Lpath/to/dependencies

# These libs should be linked statically
LDFLAGS += -static
LDFLAGS += -llib1
LDFLAGS += -llib2
LDFLAGS += -llib3

# Libs after this should be linked dynamically.
LDFLAGS += -Wl, -Bdynamic
LDFLAGS += -lz         # If i dont specify these three libraries (z, pthread, dl) 
LDFLAGS += -lpthread   # I get undefined reference errors 
LDFLAGS += -ldl
```

When I call make, the program compiles and links just fine, but when I try to execute it I get the error: `bash: ./program: No such file or directory`. 
But the file DOES exist.

When I remove the `-static` flag from the linker, the program can be excecuted just fine, but the dependencies are linked dynamically, which is not what I want :(.

So when I call `file` on the program, that was made with the `-static` flag, I get this:

`program: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /usr/lib/libc.so.1, for GNU/Linux 4.9.0, not stripped`

The problem seems to be that the interpreter is set to `/usr/lib/libc.so.1` and not to `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` as it should usually be. At least it is, when I compile without the `-static` option.

What I found out is that the 'interpreter' is in reality the shared library loader and from what I read, I now assume that the bash tells me it can not find the program because the library loader is just wrong (Even though I don't quite understand the details of this).

So basically my question is: Why does the library loader get set to `libc.so` when I specify the `-static` option to the linker and how can I tell the linker to use the correct library loader when `-static` is specified?

Comment: Found a workaround as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically. By using -l:liblibname.a. This worked aswell as the solution from n.m.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error is mixing `-static` and `-Bdynamic` as both compiler and linker flags. Don't do that. If you use `-Wl`, gcc just blindly pass  these flags to the linker, but if you don't, it rearranges the entire link line. (check what it does with `gcc -v`).

The mix creates an inconsistent and erroneous link command. I have no idea why gcc doesn't at least warn about that, but it doesn't, and silently sets the dynamic loader to a non-existent file.

You want to use `-Wl,-Bstatic` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` consistently throughout. Not `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic`, as gcc logic is different from that of ld.

This will create a correct dynamically linked executable with some static libs linked in.

Comment: It worked, you're a hero. Thank you.

Comment: You're my hero as well.