# CPython: how to link an external library (C or C++) to an extension

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x, cpython

I'm trying to implement an extension that requires use of external libraries. How can I configure include files, libraries and the path where dynamic libraries should be found?

I've tried not adding these parameters and it seems compiling without any error but then, if I try to import the module, I obtain a segmentation fault error probably due to something lacking in configuration settings or setup.py.

Comment: This is compiler specific... Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using g++ on Ubuntu.

Comment: Suppose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20728782/1312382) is what you are after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telling gcc directly to link a library statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically)

Comment: @Aconcagua I need to set it using setup.py in order to compile the CPython extension. I don't think it is a duplicate of the post you cited.

Comment: Following the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#library-options), try naming the libraries with a leading colon, probably you then need to add the library ending. If not working, you should be able to use the [extra_link_args](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#other-options) for this purpose.