# Using a static library in a Linux project of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a Linux project in VS 2017 Community Edition. The project includes a dynamic .so file. 
That works so far. I now want to statically link this library as a .a file. How can I achieve this in the project settings? 
I have found nothing. For g ++, a **-static** or **-Bstatic** should be in front of **-llibname** on the command line. 
In the project settings under **Linker-> All Options-> Additional Options** I have "**-(B)static -llibname**". 
But it does not work, that **-(B)static** is not in the generated command line. Does anyone know how it works?

Comment: To statically link the FOO library with your project, you just need to link the static FOO.a archive library to the project.  FOO.so is a shared object library, which is not a static library.  If you cannot compile FOO source into FOO.a, then you may have some luck doing an `objdump -d` to disassemble and then to recompile into .o files, then create the static archive library (FOO.a) from those .o files.  But that sounds difficult.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build you library as a static library Then simply specify the library name (without the `lib` prefix or `.a` extension) as you did for the dynamic library.

Static libraries are simply an archive of all the object files (`ar` command). If you're using an MSBuild project, specify Static Library as the Configuration Type in project properties / General / Project Defaults.

GCC will search for dynamic libraries (`.so`) on the lib path(s) first, then static libraries (`.a`). If you have both and want to force static linking there is some very helpful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically).