# Linking GCC to external library?

Tags: c

I am trying to use a library provided by course module in C.

I have the following installed:

- MinGW32 - Base
- Visual Code

**Hello.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libcs1010/include/cs1010.h"
int main()
{
   // library method
   cs1010_print_double(10);
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
undefined reference to `cs1010_print_double'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Directory Structure:**

```
└───hello.c
└───libcs1010
    ├───include
    |     └───cs1010.h
    ├───lib
    |     └───libcs1010.a
    └───src
          └───cs1010.c
```

How can I run GCC such that i can link to the **libcs1010.a** file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telling gcc directly to link a library statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically)

Comment: Add the library as if it were an seperate object file. `gcc -c hello.c` `gcc -o hello hello.o libcs1010.a`