# How to force link to static library over .so?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Our code is linking to a number of libraries. I place a compiled libfoo.a into relative directory libs, and write:

g++ mycode -L libs -lfoo

to my surprise, the executable size does not change. So I ran ldd and found that the original library iss still linked dynamically. It's in /usr/lib/xxx

How do I specify that the static library take precedence over the dynamic one in the system libraries?

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically  (g++ shares options with gcc)

Answer (score 0):

Use -static before your linker options