# Linking error for cuda separate compilation mode and static linking of cudart

Tags: c++, cuda, static-libraries, linker-errors, nvcc

Basically, my goal is the following: I want to create a program using CUDA SDK Toolkit and I want to run this program on systems which have installed NVIDIA GPUs and NVIDIA drivers but not necessary CUDA Toolkit. My idea was to link cuda libraries statically. Well, I failed to do it even for a simple case.
Let me show you it.
I have three files: main.cpp, kernel.cu and  header.h. The content of these files is below.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"
int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 5;
    const int a[arraySize] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const int b[arraySize] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    int c[arraySize] = { 0 };

    // Add vectors in parallel.
    addWithCuda(c, a, b, arraySize);
    printf("{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {%d,%d,%d,%d,%d}\n",
        c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]);


    return 0;
}
```

**header.h**

```
#pragma once
void addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size);
```

**kernel.cu**

```
#include "header.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

void addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size)
{
    int *dev_a = 0;
    int *dev_b = 0;
    int *dev_c = 0;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
    addKernel<<<1, size>>>(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }
    
    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
}
```

While I do not really think that the context of the code is important, I nevertheless decided to present it.

Then I have two files: run and run_static.

**run**

```
g++ -c main.cpp;
nvcc -c kernel.cu;
g++ main.o kernel.o -o test -L/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64 -lcudart -lcudadevrt
```

**run_static**

```
g++ -c main.cpp;
nvcc -c kernel.cu;
g++ main.o kernel.o -o test_static -L/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64 -lcudart_static -lcudadevrt
```

I could use **make** but I have decided to simplify everything.

Well, **./run** creates **test** executable which in turn produces the correct output. This is the case of a dynamic linking.
However, **./run_static** does not create **test_static**. Instead, it throws an error:

```
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::globalState::initializeDriverEntrypoints()':
(.text+0x10990): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::globalState::initializeDriverEntrypoints()':
(.text+0x109ba): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::globalState::initializeDriverEntrypoints()':
(.text+0x109e6): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::globalState::initializeDriverEntrypoints()':
(.text+0x10a12): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::globalState::initializeDriverEntrypoints()':
(.text+0x10a3e): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o):(.text+0x10a6a): more undefined references to `dlsym' follow
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::globalState::loadDriverInternal()':
(.text+0x13c52): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::globalState::loadDriverInternal()':
(.text+0x13c84): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::globalState::initializeDriverInternal()':
(.text+0x15f55): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosSemaphoreSignal(sem_t*)':
(.text+0x4e1e5): undefined reference to `sem_post'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosSemaphoreWait(sem_t*, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x4e215): undefined reference to `sem_trywait'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosSemaphoreWait(sem_t*, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x4e22a): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosSemaphoreWait(sem_t*, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x4e2ec): undefined reference to `sem_timedwait'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosSemaphoreDestroy(sem_t*)':
(.text+0x4e325): undefined reference to `sem_destroy'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosSemaphoreCreate(sem_t*, int)':
(.text+0x4e349): undefined reference to `sem_init'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `__tcf_4':
cuosLinux.cpp:(.text+0x4f4b1): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `__tcf_0':
cuosLinux.cpp:(.text+0x4f4e1): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `__tcf_1':
cuosLinux.cpp:(.text+0x4f511): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `__tcf_2':
cuosLinux.cpp:(.text+0x4f541): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `__tcf_3':
cuosLinux.cpp:(.text+0x4f571): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x4fedc): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x4fee8): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x4ff0a): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x4ff16): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x4ff2c): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x4ff7c): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x4ff88): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x4ffaa): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x4ffb6): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x4ffcc): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x5001c): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x50028): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x5004a): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x50056): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x5006c): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x500bc): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x500c8): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x500ea): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x500f6): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x5010c): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x50153): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x5015f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x50181): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x5018d): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInit()':
(.text+0x501a3): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosHasThreadExited(cudart::CUOSthread_st*)':
(.text+0x51ddb): undefined reference to `pthread_kill'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosThreadDetach(cudart::CUOSthread_st*)':
(.text+0x51df9): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosThreadCreateWithName(cudart::CUOSthread_st**, int (*)(void*), void*, char const*)':
(.text+0x51eb6): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosCondCreateWithSharedFlag(pthread_cond_t*, int)':
(.text+0x52135): undefined reference to `pthread_condattr_setpshared'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosOnce(int*, void (*)())':
(.text+0x52155): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosTryAcquireWriterLock(void**)':
(.text+0x52198): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_trywrlock'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosTryAcquireReaderLock(void**)':
(.text+0x521c8): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_tryrdlock'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInitRWLockEx(void**, void*, unsigned long)':
(.text+0x52249): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlockattr_init'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInitRWLockEx(void**, void*, unsigned long)':
(.text+0x5225a): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInitRWLockEx(void**, void*, unsigned long)':
(.text+0x52269): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_init'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosTryEnterCriticalSection(pthread_mutex_t*)':
(.text+0x52295): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInitializeCriticalSectionWithSharedFlag(pthread_mutex_t*, int)':
(.text+0x522fc): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInitializeCriticalSectionWithSharedFlag(pthread_mutex_t*, int)':
(.text+0x52321): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInitializeCriticalSectionWithSharedFlag(pthread_mutex_t*, int)':
(.text+0x5232f): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInitializeCriticalSectionWithSharedFlag(pthread_mutex_t*, int)':
(.text+0x5234a): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosTlsSetValue(unsigned int, void*)':
(.text+0x52418): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosTlsAlloc(void (*)(void*))':
(.text+0x52460): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosFreeLibrary(void*)':
(.text+0x52585): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosLoadLibrary(char const*)':
(.text+0x525a5): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosPosixInit()':
(.text+0x527ac): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosPosixInit()':
(.text+0x527b8): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosPosixInit()':
(.text+0x527da): undefined reference to `dlvsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosPosixInit()':
(.text+0x527e6): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosPosixInit()':
(.text+0x527fc): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `__tcf_0':
cuos_common_posix.cpp:(.text+0x52ba1): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosDestroyRWLock(void**)':
(.text+0x52bc8): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosLoadLibraryUnsafe(char const*)':
(.text+0x52c05): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInitRWLock(void**)':
(.text+0x52c51): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlockattr_init'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInitRWLock(void**)':
(.text+0x52c89): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosInitRWLock(void**)':
(.text+0x52c98): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_init'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosThreadJoin(cudart::CUOSthread_st*, int*)':
(.text+0x52ccf): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosCondCreateShared(pthread_cond_t*)':
(.text+0x533dc): undefined reference to `pthread_condattr_setpshared'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosCondCreate(pthread_cond_t*)':
(.text+0x53439): undefined reference to `pthread_condattr_setpshared'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosShmCloseEx(cudart::cuosShmInfoEx_st*, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x534e6): undefined reference to `shm_unlink'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosShmOpenNamedEx(void*, char const*, unsigned long, cudart::cuosShmInfoEx_st**)':
(.text+0x535b1): undefined reference to `shm_open'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosShmCreateNamedEx(void*, char const*, unsigned long, cudart::cuosShmInfoEx_st**)':
(.text+0x537cf): undefined reference to `shm_open'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosShmCreateNamedEx(void*, char const*, unsigned long, cudart::cuosShmInfoEx_st**)':
(.text+0x537e9): undefined reference to `shm_unlink'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosVirtualReserveInRange(unsigned long, void*, void*, unsigned long)':
(.text+0x53a31): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosDestroyRWLockEx(void**)':
(.text+0x52174): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosReleaseReaderLock(void**)':
(.text+0x52184): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosAcquireWriterLock(void**)':
(.text+0x521f4): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosAcquireReaderLock(void**)':
(.text+0x52204): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosTlsGetValue(unsigned int)':
(.text+0x52434): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosTlsFree(unsigned int)':
(.text+0x52444): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosGetProcAddress(void*, char const*)':
(.text+0x52571): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosLoadLibrary(char const*)':
(.text+0x525b3): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosReleaseWriterLock(void**)':
(.text+0x52a44): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosLoadLibraryUnsafe(char const*)':
(.text+0x52c13): undefined reference to `dlopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Clearly, I am missing something simple.

**Update**. I tried

```
g++ -c main.cpp;
nvcc -c kernel.cu;
g++ main.o kernel.o -o test -L/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64  -static -lcudadevrt -ldl -pthread -lrt -lcudart_static
```

and

```
g++ -c main.cpp;
nvcc -c kernel.cu;
g++ main.o kernel.o -o test -L/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64 -static -lcudart_static -lcudadevrt -ldl -lrt -pthread
```

In both cases I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Update 2.**

What worked for me

```
-lcudadevrt -lcudart_static -lrt -pthread -ldl -lc  -lpthread -Bstatic -lgcc -lstdc++ -ldf
```

You need to link it with -L$(YOUR_PATH_TO_gclib)

Comment: Add `-ldl -pthread`  to your link line.

Comment: Use nvcc to do the linking abd specify the  --cudart static option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `libdl`, `libpthread` and `librt`, add the following to your link line:

```
-ldl -pthread -lrt
```

They are dependencies of `libcudart`, to check for others, run `ldd` on the cuda shared object files.

---

Edited based on OPs comment.

Also, note that with the GCC linker, you will need to wrap the library dependencies with: `-Wl,--start-group -lmylib -lmyotherlib -Wl,--end-group`, if you are not aware of the order dependency (what depends on what).

Comment: Are they static libraries?

Comment: When  you link with `-l`, by default the linker will search for shared objects first. If you want to link statically, you will have to spell out the name of the static lib in full. [See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically). But I do not recommend linking either of these libs statically, they should be present on any system.

Comment: Gives me an 
 error./usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o): In function `cudart::cuosShmCloseEx(cudart::cuosShmInfoEx_st*, unsigned int, unsigned int)':
(.text+0x534e6): undefined reference to `shm_unlink'
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64/libcudart_static.a(libcudart_static.a.o)

Comment: I think you are missing `-lrt`. Add the new error to your question. For next time, you just have to find out what lib has the missing symbols you need and add it to your link time (assuming it is present on your system).