# Link static library with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

How can I link a static library with cmake? The library I'm trying to link is in the project directory `lib/lib.a` and the only source file is `main.cpp`. The `.h` file of the library `lib.a` is in `inlcude/library.h`. 
Doesn't work I:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(FireUp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

link_directories(lib)

add_executable(FireUp main.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(FireUp lib.a)
```

Output:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: XXX/_projects/FireUp
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable FireUp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l-Wl,-Bdynamic
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/build.make:84: FireUp] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: FireUp] Error 2
```

Doesn't work II:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(FireUp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(FireUp main.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(FireUp lib/lib.a)
```

Output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target FireUp
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable FireUp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llib/lib.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/build.make:103: FireUp] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:102: CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:137: FireUp] Error 2
```

Doesn't work III:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(FireUp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(FireUp main.cpp lib/lib.a)
```

Output:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable FireUp
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
XXX/_projects/FireUp/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `hello()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/build.make:103: FireUp] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:102: CMakeFiles/FireUp.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:137: FireUp] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding existing libraries to cmake is adding an "IMPORTED" library.

```
add_library(somelib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET somelib PROPERTY
             IMPORTED_LOCATION lib/lib.a)
target_link_libraries(FireUp PRIVATE somelib)
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/guide/importing-exporting/index.html

`lib.a` looks like a bad name, I suggest naming the library like `lib<something_here>.a` for example `liblib.a`, so that UNIX compilers can search for it with `-l` flag. Also research [Telling gcc directly to link a library statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically) .