# Statically linked binary for kcat or kafkacat

Tags: apache-kafka, makefile, build, kcat

While trying to build kcat (Github edenhill/kcat - formerly known as kafkacat), I've stumbled upon some issues with library dependencies after the build has been successful, even though the build script has specific parameters for a static build.
The use case is for building a binary that should theoretically work on multiple versions of the OS, where in my case is RHEL 7 & 8.
Building kcat on either RHEL 7 or RHEL 8, will make the build dependent on the libraries (libcrypto.so.1.1 and libssl.so.1.1) from the version hosting the build:

```
(rhel7)# ldd kcat
./kcat: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by ./kcat)
./kcat: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by ./kcat)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdb4dfc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0be4261000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0be405d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0be3e41000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f0be3c39000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0be3a23000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found
    libssl.so.1.1 => not found
    libsasl2.so.3 => /lib64/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007f0be3806000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f0be35ec000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f0be33b5000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f0be3168000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f0be2e7f000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f0be2c4c000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f0be2a48000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f0be27de000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0be2410000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0be4563000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f0be2200000)
    libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007f0be1ffd000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f0be1df9000)
    libidn.so.11 => /lib64/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f0be1bc6000)
    libssh2.so.1 => /lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007f0be1999000)
    libssl3.so => /lib64/libssl3.so (0x00007f0be1740000)
    libsmime3.so => /lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007f0be1518000)
    libnss3.so => /lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007f0be11e9000)
    libnssutil3.so => /lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f0be0fb9000)
    libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007f0be0db5000)
    libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007f0be0bb0000)
    libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007f0be0972000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f0be0763000)
    libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f0be050e000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f0be02e7000)
    libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f0be0075000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f0bdfc12000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f0bdf9b0000)
```

On the building host:

```
(rhel8)# ldd kcat
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd9096e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007febf8734000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007febf8530000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007febf8310000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007febf8108000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007febf7ef1000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007febf7a08000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007febf7774000)
    libsasl2.so.3 => /lib64/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007febf7556000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007febf733f000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007febf7116000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007febf6ec1000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007febf6bd8000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007febf69c1000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007febf67bd000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007febf652f000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007febf616a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007febf8ab6000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007febf5f59000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007febf5d55000)
    libnghttp2.so.14 => /lib64/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007febf5b2e000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /lib64/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007febf5910000)
    libssh.so.4 => /lib64/libssh.so.4 (0x00007febf56a1000)
    libpsl.so.5 => /lib64/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007febf5490000)
    libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00007febf5242000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007febf5032000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib64/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007febf4e25000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007febf4bfb000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /lib64/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007febf487a000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib64/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007febf4659000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007febf43d5000)
```

The boostrap script seems to mark the following libraries as dynamic (most of them, if not all of them are installed from RHEL packages):

```
MKL_DYNAMIC_LIBS         -lavro -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lsasl2 -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt -lpthread -lrt -lz -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lssl -lcrypto -lz -ldl -lsasl2 -ldl -lresolv -lcrypt -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lcurl
```

Are there any tools, build or compile flags that might enforce building a statically linked binary (that of course, I can still use in my case)?

Thanks!

Comment: You say _the build script has specific parameters for a static build_; what parameters are those?  The decision as to whether to link statically or dynamically is made by the linker so you need to add linker options to control this.  You might find this question and answers helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically

Comment: One thing to note is that static libraries are often not provided in the normal packages for libraries, because they aren't needed at runtime.  Often there is a separate "devel" package that contains the header files and static libraries that you need to have installed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @MadScientist, I will try to use the suggestion from your first comment with -l flags. I've used the https://github.com/edenhill/kcat/blob/1.7.1/bootstrap.sh script which uses the configure script. The configure script determines the flags of the libraries and creates the Makefile.config. I've already installed all the devel libraries for most of the dependencies. Also, I've opened a Github issue, but I don't get my hopes to high on it.

Comment: I don't know anything about that project but the `configure` option `--enable-static` _usually_ means that the build of the project will create its own libraries as static in addition to shared.  It doesn't mean that it will try to use the static libraries from other projects.

Comment: It seems "--enable-static" is only for librdkafka. I see in my logs that anyhow others are dynamically linked:
MKL_DYNAMIC_LIBS         -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt -lz -lssl -lzstd -llz4 -lcrypto and then later: 
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -L/.../kafkacat/librdkafka/lib/ -L/.../kafkacat/librdkafka/lib/ kcat.o format.o tools.o input.o -o kcat /.../librdkafka/build-deployables/lib/librdkafka.a -L/.../librdkafka/build-deployables/lib -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt -lz -lssl -lzstd -llz4 -lcrypto