# Incorrect $SystemID in Mathematica

Tags: c++, wolfram-mathematica, shared-libraries, 32bit-64bit, mathlink

I am trying to link Mathlink libraries in mathematica. I am using a x86_64-suse-linux OS, but when I check $SystemID in Mathematica, it tells me I am using 'Linux' instead of 'Linux-x86-64'.

This is a problem because if I try to link the library as

```
g++ cpp2mma.cpp -L/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux/CompilerAdditions/ -lML32i3 -lpthread -lstdc++ -lm -lrt
```

(the 32 bit version - and the only library in Linux/)

I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible 
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux/CompilerAdditions//libML32i3.so when searching for -lML32i3
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux/CompilerAdditions//libML32i3.a when searching for -lML32i3
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lML32i3 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

however, if I try to link it as

```
g++ cpp2mma.cpp -L/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/ -lML64i3 -lpthread -lstdc++ -lm -lrt
```

it compiles just fine, but if I try to run it I get the following error:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libML64i3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This file obviously exists as running 'locate libML64i3.so' yields:

```
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libML64i3.so
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libML64i3.so
```

Am I correct in assuming that the problem lies in the fact that Mathematica thinks that I am not running a 32 bit system? If so, what do I do?

Comment: You're definitely using a 32-bit version of Mathematica.  What value do you get from `SystemInformation["Kernel", "ReleaseID"]`?

Comment: Could you post cpp2mma.cpp, please ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in Mathematica.  The kernel is never running -- from the perspective of e system you are compiling and launching an ELF executable.  libML64i3 will start a kernel for you, but its not getting loaded here.

There are several ways to get the linker to find `libML64i3.so` at runtime

1. Export the directory containing `libML64i3.so` through `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (generally not a good idea)
2. use an entry in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` or `/etc/ld.so.conf` to indicate that `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions` should be part of the library search path -- look at `ldconfig(8)`.
3. Symlink `libML64i3.so` somewhere already in the library search path
4. Link to a static version of libML, as described in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698321/g-linker-force-static-linking-if-static-library-exists).

To deal with the compile-time linker errors, you could compile your application 32-bit (by passing `-m32` to `g++`).  If you did this, you would get a runtime message griping about not being able to find the 32-bit version of libML, which would require the same solution as above.

I'm not sure why $SystemID is returning a value indicating you are running the 32-bit kernel.  That probably has something to do with how you are starting Mathematica.  On CentOS 5-7-x86_64, I have

```
host 11% ls -l $(which math)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 51 Nov  8 16:27 /usr/local/bin/math -> \
    /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/Executables/math
host 12% math
Mathematica 8.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2011 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= $SystemID

Out[1]= Linux-x86-64
```