# libstdc++.dll now required in every project directory for MinGW?

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, mingw

Just now I've found that I am unable to run C++ programs compiled through MinGW (g++) without having a copy of the libstdc++ dll in the same directory. This never used to be the case.

I recently installed CMake, which I think may be causing the issue, but I can't say for sure. How can I fix this?

I'm getting the error "The procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library ".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [g++ linker: force static linking if static library exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698321/g-linker-force-static-linking-if-static-library-exists)

Comment: Add the `-static` flag (or more elaborate in the above answer if you want some libraries to use shared linkage). If you're distributing these apps, it's highly unlikely other users will have the MinGW runtime already installed. You should do it for your own sake and for others.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an older version of libstdc++.dll is being found on the search path if you don't have it in the same directory as the executable. Use 'which' to find out the path of the libstdc++.dll that is being found instead and possibly fix your PATH. Either that or live with having to have multiple copies on disk.